# How I can read and storage a JSON object from Dynamodb into React?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am getting a JSON object from a Lambda function. When I get a specific value from the JSON object and storage it into an array it works fine. I don't know how to storage the whole JSON object on any structure in React. The idea is to storage the JSON object to make some calculations later with the values.

I am using "json.map" get the values

Here is where I call the API gateway and fecth the json object:

```
componentDidMount() {

    fetch('https://llzgbat7hi.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/api/getrange?domain=demo.com&cont=5')
       .then(res => res.json())
       .then(json => {

                   const RecordRowCount = json.map(item => item.RecordRowCount)
                    this.setState({ tasks: RecordRowCount })
         });


 }
```

The code above show how I get the value RecordRowCount and storage it into an array but I need to fecth the whole JSON object

This is the actual JSON structure returned from DB:

```
[
  {
    "Id": "123455",
    "Customer": 100,
    "Domain": "demo.com",
    "OrgName": "demo.com",
    "ReportMetadataEmail": "demo@me.com",
    "ReportMetadataExtraContactInfo": "postmaster@demo.com"
  },
  {
    "Id": "123456",
    "Customer": 101,
    "Domain": "demo1.com",
    "OrgName": "demo1.com",
    "ReportMetadataEmail": "demo1@me.com",
    "ReportMetadataExtraContactInfo": "postmaster@demo1.com"
  }
]
```

I want to map that JSON object into any React structure (Ex Array)

Comment: hi, why don't you just try : `this.setState({ tasks: json })` ?

Comment: the items in the array don't have a `RecordRowCount` so you'll get an array of undefineds

Comment: agree with @Taki. Try this.setState({ tasks: json }, ()=>console.log(this.state.tasks[0])) instead and see if your this.state.tasks[0] holds your first record.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot @AppleJam, @Taki and @tcoulson

You were right. I just assigned json to tasks and it worked, now my tasks array hold all the json object.

Thanks

Comment: For the future benefit of other users, you could edit this answer and post the solution.